# Login to the application in one webbrowser instance on other tabs

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

for example I have two applications in PHP with same username and password. I want to access these two applications in same browser (eg: Mozilla Firefox) - sequential tabs.If I login both the application sequentially, either or both the application logs out automatically.

consider first application named: example1 
host: http://localhost/example1
username:example
password:example123

consider first application named: example2
host: http://localhost/example2
username:example
password:example123

How to access more than one applications in php with same username and password in same browser - sequential tabs ?

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

It is not about PHP but about your web browser configuration.

You should turn your cookies off - sessions are often implemented by using them and in one web browser same cookies are used. With cookies off sessions will be executed by using URL id.

[Here you can find how to disable cookie in Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?hl=en).

The other option is of course to use many instances of web browser or even many web browsers.

Comment: Another solution is to personalize the cookie of each application and verify it before login.